# What is the difference between is+ Noun or is +of + Noun

Tags: grammar

I am confuse below sentence,
Is it right in subject place?

> the people is of importance

or

> the people is importance

Comment: Where did you find this sentence? Did you make it up?

Comment: You may find it usefull to have a think about joining our sister site [ell.se].

Comment: "*I am confuse below sentence*" is not valid English. It could be written as "*I am confused about the sentence below*" The word "confuse" is a verb, while "confused" is a past participle which can function as an  adjective

Answer (score 2):

**The people are of importance** 
or 
**The people are important**

1. *People* is plural. Even though it may be a rough synonym for *nation* (*the people*), it is plural.
2. *Important* is an adjective. *Importance* is a noun.

Comment: +1.  Perhaps worth saying that *important* is [far more common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=are+of+importance%2Care+important%2Cis+of+importance%2Cis+important&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Care%20of%20importance%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Care%20important%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cis%20of%20importance%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cis%20important%3B%2Cc0) than *of importance*